# How to write a for loop, with a counter, for a nested list?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to select only even values from a nested list and also keep track of how many even numbers were in each element of the nested list. For example, if I have  I would want to print out all of the even numbers and also the total number of even numbers that are in each elements.

I have been tinckering with my code, but I either end up just getting the counter to print 1 or it counts all of the values in each of the elements of the list. Would appreciate some insight!

```py
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2,6, 8], [12, 13, 14]]
for element in nested_list:

    for value in element:
        i = 0
        if value % 2 == 0:
            print(value)
        i = i + 1 
    print(f'This element contained {i} even numbers')
```

I would like to get something like this back:

2

4

There are 2 even numbers in this element

2

6

8

There are 3 even numbers in this element

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but your indentation is off:

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2,6, 8], [12, 13, 14]]
for element in nested_list:
    i = 0
    for value in element:
        if value % 2 == 0:
            print(value)
            i += 1  # This needs to be indented so that it's under the if statement!
    print(f'This element contained {i} even numbers')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Everytime you went to a new value, your i variable was getting declared again as 0. Be creating the variable outside the nested for loop, we have a continuous counter that will increment as it goes through each value of element. Once we get to a new element, i will be re-declared at 0.

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2,6, 8], [12, 13, 14]]
for element in nested_list:
    i = 0;

    for value in element:
        if value % 2 == 0:
        print(value)
        i = i + 1 
    print(f'This element contained {i} even numbers')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using list comprehension.

Refer below code to get even num list and print len of even num list from nested list.

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2,6, 8], [12, 13, 14]]

for sub_list in nested_list:
    even_nums = [i for i in sub_list if not i % 2]
    print('Even nums ', even_nums, f'\nThis element contained {len(even_nums)} even numbers ')
```

Refer below code if you only want in sum of even nums from nested list list.

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2,6, 8], [12, 13, 14]]

for sub_list in nested_list:
    total_evens = sum(1 for i in sub_list if not i % 2)
    print(f'This element contained {total_evens} even numbers ')
```

Second solution is generator expression which returning 1 if num is even and this generator expression we can pass directly to sum() function.

This is more memory efficient as generator objects does lazy evaluation, also we don't need to keep different integers in another list.